# How can I detect when wifi / ethernet / hotspot drops in swift for OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I've search around in SO and in Apple documentation and I can't seem to find how to do this.

I have an app I am making and I want to detect when the network connection drops and print "Network Dropped" to the console when this happens.

Is it possible using swift for OS X?

Comment: You don't need to tag Xcode in any of the questions you're asking, DanTdd.

Comment: Oh, sorry! @nhgrif I'll stop tagging it.

Comment: Same for objC if you want an answer in swift.

Comment: @Jef I actually was happy with an answer in either just so i could get a path to explore

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Download [this](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/master/External/Reachability) from github.

**2.** Add these files in your projects

```
Reachability.h
Reachability.m
```

**3.** In `ViewController.h` add:

```
@class Reachability;
```

**4.** Add variable `Reachability* internetReachable;` in `ViewController.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    Reachability* internetReachable;
}
```

**5.** Add `Reachability.h` in `ViewController.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
```

**6.** Add following lines in YourViewController.m

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                       addObserver:self 
                       selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) 
                       name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                       object:nil];

    internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReachable startNotifier];
}
```

**7.** Add the following function

```
-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Or us the SC System Configuration framework directly. Which would be hideous in Swift.

Comment: Bear in mind that any device that can run Swift code also is multi homing so a drop on one interface doesn't always mean no network